# Displaying job status in a jQuery Datatable

Tags: beginner, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-datatables

I was wondering if there was a better way to write this:

```
#Define Jquery Datatable
if $('#dtable').length
  table = $('#dtable').DataTable()

#If job is created, make new row in Jquery datatables
if data.status == "Created" then (
  count = 0
  new_data = [
    data.job_id
    data.start_ip
    data.end_ip
    data.ilo_username
    data.ilo_password
    data.status
    create_date
    '<a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="/ilo_scan_jobs/' + data.job_id + '">Details</a>'
  ]
  new_row = table.row.add(new_data).draw().nodes().to$().find('td').each ->
    $(this).attr 'id', 'td_' + count++ + '_' + data.job_id
  new_row
  id = $('#row' + data.job_id).val()
  table.row(new_row).node().id = 'row' + data.job_id
)

#If job status is running
else if data.status != "Created" and data.status != "Job Deleted" and data.status != "Scan Complete" then (
  #Update Jquery datatable if it exists
  if $('#dtable').length
    table.cell('#td_5_' + data.job_id).data wait_status

  #Update job detail status if it exists
  if $(detail_status).length
    $(detail_status).html wait_status

  #Detail Status  
  if $(respond_message).length then (
    if data.count == null or data.server_count != 0
      $(respond_message).html wait_message
    else if data.server_count == 0
      $(respond_message).html no_respond
  )
) 
#If job status is complete
else if data.status == "Scan Complete" then (
  #Update Jquery Datatable if it exists
  if $('#dtable').length
    table.cell('#td_5_' + data.job_id).data(data.status)

  #Update job detail status if it exists
  if $(detail_status).length
    $(detail_status).html data.status

  #Detail Status  
  if $(respond_message).length then (
    if data.server_count == 0
      $(respond_message).html no_respond
    else if data.server_count != 0
      $(respond_message).html respond_finish
  )

#Remove disabled class on buttons if exists
  if $('#edit_disable_' + data.job_id).length and data.status == 'Scan Complete'
    $('#edit_disable_' + data.job_id).removeClass 'disabled'
  if $('#delete_disable_' + data.job_id).length and data.status == 'Scan Complete'
    $('#delete_disable_' + data.job_id).removeClass 'disabled'
)
#If job is deleted, remove table row from Jquery datatable
else if data.status == "Job Deleted"
  tr = "#row" + data.job_id
  table.row(tr).remove().draw()
```

Even though it is working, the code seems a little sloppy to me with all the if/else statements.  Is there any way to simplify it?  I'm new to coffeescript.

Comment: There are few things that can be shortened, but first things first - what is the `detail_status`? I don't see its declaration anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you may benefit from the fact that in Coffee (and in JS, too), the following code

```
if condition
  variable = value
```

can be expressed simpler as

```
variable = condition && value
```

Therefore, the declaration of the `table` may be written as

```
table = $('#dtable').length && $('#dtable').DataTable()
```

Later in the code, you should not check again for the `$('#dtable').length` but you should check if the `table` has a value, possibly with [the existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#existential-operator). For example, replace the

```
if $('#dtable').length
    table.cell('#td_5_' + data.job_id).data wait_status
```

with

```
table?.cell('#td_5_' + data.job_id).data wait_status
```

I don't know what the `detail_status` is but I suppose it is a string selector. Therefore, you don't need to check if it is available in the DOM. JQuery will do nothing if there is no such element, so you can safely call `$(detail_status).html wait_status` without checking for its length. The same goes for e.g. `removeClass` method.

You can also use Coffee's [string interpolation](http://coffeescript.org/#strings) and replace the `"#row" + data.job_id` with `"#row#{data.job_id}"` (and similar).

Last but not least, try replacing multiple conditions like `if data.status != "Created" and data.status != "Job Deleted" and data.status != "Scan Complete"` with one statement with the `in` operator, i.e. `if data.status not in ['Created', 'Job Deleted', 'Scan Complete']`.

Comment: Thanks for the info fracz.  After defining table into a condition and value as you suggested, I tried `table?.cell('#td_5_' + data.job_id).data wait_status`, but I am getting the error that `table.cell is not a function`.  Still playing around with it...

Comment: Also tried `table.cell('#td_5_' + data.job_id).data wait_status if table?` but still get the same result.  The problem appears to be that it is  running `table.cell` without first checking if it exists.

Comment: My fault. If there is no `#dtable`, after the `table = $('#dtable').length && $('#dtable').DataTable()` the `table` gets value `0`, which passes the existential operator (the value exists). Replace it with `table = $('#dtable').DataTable() if $('#dtable').length` and the rest of the code should work as I have written.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick.  I'll continue to try and clean it up.  This helped a lot.